# which is the better way to keep and load images at run time in android?

Tags: android, image, drawable, assets

I have up to 200 large scale fixed images and i need to handle it at run time.

[**Consider performance and apk size**]

1.where i can  keep this images(Asset folder or drawables)?
2.currently following this technique image.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.mango);
3.Any other better way is there?

Answer (score 0):

Please use image loader for many images. I hope [Image Loader](http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/android-imageloader-load-images-sequencially-in-the-background/) is very help full for you...

Comment: It looks image downloading from external source. but have static images no need to download..

Comment: then all images put in drawable folder and use use img.setBackground(R.drawable.img1);